# Compiling opencv3 get "libgdal.so.20 undefined reference"

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

While I try to compile opencv3 I got this error:

> ../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.2: undefined reference
>   "TIFFReadDirectory@LIBTIFF_4.0" //usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined
>   reference "TIFFLastDirectory@LIBTIFF_4.0"
>   ../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.2: undefined reference
>   "TIFFWriteEncodedStrip@LIBTIFF_4.0"
>   ../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.2: undefined reference
>   "TIFFIsTiled@LIBTIFF_4.0" //usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined reference
>   "TIFFSwabArrayOfShort@LIBTIFF_4.0" //usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined
>   reference "TIFFIsByteSwapped@LIBTIFF_4.0" //usr/lib/libgdal.so.20:
>   undefined reference "TIFFFlushData@LIBTIFF_4.0"
>   //usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined reference
>   "TIFFFreeDirectory@LIBTIFF_4.0"
>   ../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.2: undefined reference
>   "TIFFScanlineSize@LIBTIFF_4.0" //usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined
>   reference "TIFFWriteEncodedTile@LIBTIFF_4.0"

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

How can I solve? I already installed libgdal20 and libgdal-dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using this (modules) https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib

As the README shows I did this:

```
$ cd <opencv_build_directory>
$ cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<opencv_contrib>/modules <opencv_source_directory>
$ make -j5
```

Having directory "opencv" and opencv_contrib in the same directory (my home directory) I typed:

```
$ cd opencv/build
$ cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/helias/opencv/modules  /home/helias/opencv
$ make -j 8
```

Note: 8 = is the number of my CPU cores